# Trying to get google maps to zoom and center, can't get my head round it

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming, fitbounds, setbounds

I've got a piece of code here that plots a group of paths on a map. I'm trying to get the map to zoom and centre so all the paths are visible, but I can't get anything to work. Here's what the code looks like before I started:

```
var points = new Array();
var pointsData = [];
var pointsData = $('#master-' + r + ' > #route-data').html();
if (pointsData != '')
{
    var pointsArray = JSON.parse(pointsData);
    for (var p=0; p<pointsArray.length; p++) {
        points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(pointsArray[p][0], pointsArray[p][1]));
    }
    $.OverMap.drawRoute(points);
}
else $.OverMap.drawDirections({preserveViewport:false});
```

And after fiddling with it:

```
map = this.map.map;

map.fitBounds(this.map.bounds);
zoomChangeBoundsListener = 
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        if (this.getZoom()){
            this.setZoom(16);
        }
});
setTimeout(function(){google.maps.event.removeListener(zoomChangeBoundsListener)}, 2000);

// Draw route
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var points = new Array();
var pointsData = [];
var pointsData = $('#master-' + r + ' > #route-data').html();
if (pointsData != '')
{
    var pointsArray = JSON.parse(pointsData);
    for (var p=0; p<pointsArray.length; p++) {
        points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(pointsArray[p][0], pointsArray[p][1]));
        bounds.extend(pointsArray[p][0], pointsArray[p][1]);
    }
    $.OverMap.drawRoute(points);
}
else $.OverMap.drawDirections({preserveViewport:false});
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the [google.maps.LatLngBounds.extend](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) takes a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) object as an argument.

not:

```
for (var p=0; p<pointsArray.length; p++) {
    points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(pointsArray[p][0], pointsArray[p][1]));
    bounds.extend(pointsArray[p][0], pointsArray[p][1]);
}
```

instead do:

```
for (var p=0; p<pointsArray.length; p++) {
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(pointsArray[p][0], pointsArray[p][1]);
    points.push(pt);
    bounds.extend(pt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code still doesn't work, but now I know one of the things I got wrong.